# Do multiple file reading in pandas respect the order?

Tags: python, pandas

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289386/loading-multiple-csv-files-of-a-folder-into-one-dataframe) I am loading multiple files of a folder into one dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("TransactionData\Promorelevant*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";") for f in files]

salesdata = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

My original windows folder looks like this:

```
A-2017-05-08
B-2017-05-09
...
```

So it is sorted based on a datestemp (which is in the filename). Is this order also kept while reading the file? I need this order to apply a filter later on, so that I know when for an entry it appears upper in the dataframe it has to filter out, if it also appears later.

Comment: Do you mean if the order is preserved in `concat` ? Because the order in `files` is definitely preserved when you call `pd.read_csv` in the list comprehension

Comment: Yes, then I mean this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this reply

[Will passing ignore_index=True to pd.concat preserve index succession within dataframes that I'm concatenating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546312/will-passing-ignore-index-true-to-pd-concat-preserve-index-succession-within-dat)

you can preserve the order of the `files` list by specifying additionally `sort=False`. Your last line of code would then look like

```
salesdata = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```